# Find the maximum values of a variable in a list

Tags: r, list

I have a list of the following structure & I intend to find the maximum value of X2 in the second variable (b) in the list

**sample data**

```
[[1]]

[[1]]$a

[1] 2

[[1]]$b

   X1  X2
1  58 1686729

2 106 1682303


[[2]]

[[2]]$a

[1] 3

[[2]]$b

   X1  X2

1  24 1642468

2  89 1695581

3 156 1634019
```

I looked into multiple filters that can be applied to the list like:

```
library(rlist)
list.filter(result, max(b$area))
```

and also tried `lapply` but with no success

```
lapply(result, function(x) x[which.max(x$b)])
```

I need the following output:

```
a      x1    x2
2      58   1686729
3      89   1695581
```

Comment: Can you add the output of `dput(your_list)` at the end of your question?

Comment: @markus added it, please understand i cant paste entire ouput so i pasted head(dput(list))

Comment: That is not reproducible, and is not `dput`

Comment: added, plz check. I changed couple variable names before but plz consider dput output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With `lapply()` you can find the max of `X2` in `$b` in each list, then `cbind()` with the `a` element.

```
l_max <- lapply(l, function(x) {
  b <- x$b
  cbind(a=x$a, b[which.max(b$X2),])
})
```

Use `bind_rows()` from `dplyr` for binding together.

```
l_max %>% 
  dplyr::bind_rows()
#     a X1      X2
# 1   2 58 1686729
# 2   3 89 1695581
```

Example data:

```
l <- list(
  list(a = 2, 
       b = data.frame(X1 = c(58, 106),  X2 = c(1686729, 1682303))),
  list(a = 3, 
       b = data.frame(X1 = c(24, 89,156),  X2 = c(1642468, 1695581,1634019)))
)
```

---

With your example:

```
l_max <- lapply(l, function(x) {
  b <- x$b
  cbind(a = x$a, b[which.max(b[,2]),]) # NOTICE I used [,2] to refer to the second column
                             #b$area works too if all df share the col name
})

l_max %>% 
  dplyr::bind_rows()
#   a  rt    area
# 1 2  58 1686729
# 2 3  89 1695581
# 3 4 101 1679889
# 4 5  88 1695983
# 5 6 105 1706445
# 6 7 121 1702019
```

---

Another solution with `purrr::map_df()` avoids the use of `bind_rows()`:

```
purrr::map_df(l, function(x) {
  b <- x$b
  cbind(a = x$a, b[which.max(b[,2]),]) 
})
```

---

All base R using `mapply()`:

```
t(mapply(function(x) {
  b <- x$b
  cbind(a = x$a, b[which.max(b[,2]),]) 
}, l))
```

Or with `Map()`:

```
do.call("rbind", Map(function(x) {
  b <- x$b
  cbind(a = x$a, b[which.max(b[,2]),]) 
}, l))
```

Comment: now as i look closer, you call `mapply()`, with one element only. So that could be simplified to `sapply()`,...then my answer would not be needed ;)

Answer (score 1):

You can also use `sapply()`:

```
t(sapply(list, function(elem){
  c(a = elem$a, elem$b[which.max(elem$b$area), ])
}))
```